# How to mock a struct if you directly access its fields

Tags: testing, go, interface, mocking

I am writing a program that acts as a client of Github API. I use https://github.com/google/go-github to access the API. I have a function that accepts a `github.Client` as one of the argumenta and uses it to retrieve commits from a pull request. I want to test this function with some fake data.

In the article here: https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2015/10/10/interfaces-and-composition-for-effective-unit-testing-in-golang/ I read, that I should create an interface that would be implemented by github client, and then in my tests, create a mock that would also implement it. My problem is, that `go-github` uses the following semantics to retrieve pull request:

`prs, resp, err := client.PullRequests.List("user", "repo", opt)`

The interfaces however allow you to specify *methods* that should be implemented, but not *fields*. So how can I mock the github.Client object so it can be used in the above semantics?

Comment: No need to mock something that has exported fields: Just make yourself a github.Client.

Comment: But I don't want a real github.Client that connects to the API. I want something that returns static data.

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to declare your own interface. Then just implement it with two different structs, the first one simply recall the github API, and the other one is your fake one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. But can I declare a field in the interface? IIUC only methods can be declared in interfaces.

Comment: so wrap it in an interface that can be mocked, or use a client that lends itself better to mocking and doesn't do this.

Comment: This reads a bit like an X-Y problem. If you need to mock the logic of your dependencies, to unit test your own code, you may just need to rethink your basic design. If you want to test how your code handles static data, you should separate out the data-processing logic in a way that makes it testable, in a way that you can feed it static mock data. Not by passing an instance of a dependency, used to retrieve that data. Just get the data from the client, and pass it to your code. In your test, pass diferent data to the same code and make sure it behaves as expected

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I thought about it. But the lack of separation of of data retrieval and handling allows me to only call the API requests that I need. Which is good due to limits. Thanks however.

Comment: @zefciu: Wouldn't wrapping the operations into custom functions be an option? ie `var callDependency = func (client *github.Client) (*wrappedGithubResponse, error) {}`, and just override those functions in your test?

Comment: Yes it would. That's the idea I accepted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be practical in your case, especially if you're using a lot of functionality from `github.Client` but you can use embedding to create a new structure that implements an interface you define.

```
type mockableClient struct {
    github.Client
}

func (mc *mockableClient) ListPRs(
owner string, repo string, opt *github.PullRequestListOptions) (
[]*github.PullRequest, *github.Response, error) {

return mc.Client.PullRequests.List(owner, repo, opt)
}


type clientMocker interface {
    Do(req *http.Request, v interface{}) (*github.Response, error)

    ListPRs(string,string,*github.PullRequestListOptions) (
[]*github.PullRequest, *github.Response, error)
}
```